# How to store integer numbers in the range of 0-9 in only 4 bits and use the same as Key in HashMap?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, bit-manipulation

I have been asked to come up with a solution where you have a file where each line represent a 10 digit phone number and we need to tell whether a given 10 digit phone number is present in the file or not.

I came up with Trie Data structure where each each children is nothing but a Map of integer as Key and Trie as Value.

```
class Trie{

   boolean isEnd;
   Map<Integer, Trie> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I can take int[] arr also to store the children.

As we have only numbers ranging from 0 - 9, so we can store these numbers in 4 bits only. Why to take 'int' or Integer as data type. How to reduce memory here?

How we can store this numbers in Map or array but not taking int as we will end up wasting lot of memory.

Moreover is there any better solution than Trie?

Comment: If your `Map` keys are numbers and they are bounded to a small amount, then an array or list as a structure has the same read-performance as the corresponding map (O(1)) but with less overhead.

Comment: My map keys are not entire phone number. Each digit of the number is the key and the rest of the digits are children,

Comment: Although you could represent a digit in just 4 bits, Java has no native 4-bit data type. So you can't save any memory that way. You could, however, store two digits in a single 8-bit value. But using a trie here probably isn't your best option, due to memory limitations. Why not a `Map<long, boolean>`? Sure, you waste the one byte `boolean` for each number, but that's a whole lot less than the memory you'll use storing pointers in your trie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going for memory efficiency, I would actually advise *against* using a trie and recommend a different data structure. As I understand it, you are only interested in answering queries of the form "have I see this phone number before?" While you could do this by treating the phone numbers as strings and throwing all of them into a trie, you wouldn't be taking advantage of the operations that tries are designed to support (fast prefix searching, retrieving elements in sorted order, etc.), so you'd be paying for things you wouldn't be using.

Moreover, let's think about the space usage of the trie. Even if every phone number had a long common prefix, each node in the trie requires space to store its child pointers. If you store even one (64-bit) pointer per node, you're using the same amount of space that you'd be using to store a 10-digit phone number (which fits comfortably into a 64-bit integer). If the phone numbers don't have long shared prefixes, you're potentially storing ten pointers per number, a huge space blowup, regardless of how big the hash table keys are.

Instead of throwing things into a trie, I'd consider just using a simple, vanilla hash table. After all, hash tables are specifically optimized to support membership queries and membership queries alone. Hashing phone numbers shouldn't be too bad, as they can be packed into 64-bit integers and hashed using a variety of simple hashing techniques. This lets you control what kind of time/space tradeoff you want to make (larger table sizes increase memory and decrease time, smaller tables increase time and decrease memory).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation w.r.t not using the trie. But in hashtable also we are wasting the 'value' field memory as we are not using it.

Secondly what about my first part of questions to store numbers from 0-9 in 4 bit in java? In case you can help me on that.

Comment: While it’s true that unused values in a hash table waste memory, let’s do some quick arithmetic. If half the entries in the table are used, each phone number essentially takes up two machine words - one for the slot it uses and one for an unused slot. With a trie, each phone number requires space for up to ten pointers without even factoring in the overhead for the map. That’s a marked difference in space that makes the hash table much more memory efficient.

Comment: He means that a hashtable stores key->value where only the key is the payload. The answer is to use a HashSet instead. Ironically, HashSet has the a slightly higher memory footprint (only by a fixed amount of bytes) as it uses HashMap internally and doesn't use the 'value' fields.

Comment: Depending on how things are implemented, sometimes hash-based containers still need some auxiliary control words associated with each entry to store data like “is this slot empty?,” “how far is this element from its home slot?,” etc. Even with that memory overhead this is still likely a better route than the trie, though.